# Error trying to call controller from route in AngularJS with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

My index.html has markup like the following (though only needed code)

index.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <div><ng-view></ng-view></div>

    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script data-main="app" src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>   
</body>
</html>
```

search.html

```
<div>{{ person.name }}</div>
```

config.js

```
"use strict";

var require = {
    paths: {
        "jQuery": "bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min",
        "angular": "bower_components/angular/angular.min",
        "angular-route": "bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min",
        "angular-mocks": "bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks",
        "angular-resource": "bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min"
        "components": "components"
    },
    shim: {
        "jQuery": {"exports": "jQuery"},
        "angular": {"exports" : "angular"},
        "angular-route": ["angular"],
        "angular-mocks": { deps: ["angular"], "exports": "angular.mock" },
        "angular-resource": ["angular"]
    },
    priority: ["angular"]
};
```

app.js

```
"use strict";

define("app", ["angular", "routes", "angular-resource", "angular-route", "jQuery"], function (angular, routes) {
    var app = angular.module("app", ["ngResource", "ngRoute"]);

    angular.element().ready(function() {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"]);
    });

    return app;
});
```

routes.js

```
"use strict";

require(["app", "components/search/search-ctrl"], function(app) {
    return app.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("/", {
            controller: "SearchCtlr", 
            templateUrl: "/app/partials/search.html"
        }).
        otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    }]);
});
```

search-ctrl.js

```
'use strict';

define("search", ["angular", "angular-resource"], function(angular) {
    var search = angular.module('search', []);
    return search;
});

require(["search"], function(search) {
    search.controller("SearchCtlr", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
        $scope.person = {
            name: "Blah"
        };
    }]);
});
```

The error I am getting is this

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-build.2801+sha.ff791c9/ng/areq?p0=SearchCtlr&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:6:472
    at Hb (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:20:239)
    at Ta (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:20:326)
    at http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:69:56
    at link (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js:7:248)
    at x (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:55:371)
    at g (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:48:280)
    at http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:47:398
    at http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:49:227
```

If I the  element out the error goes away, although the html is being loaded from the view properly.Maybe I am setting up the search component wrong?

Comment: You dont need to add the controller in the HTML since the router already links it to the template. Plus `If I take the controller out of the html, the error goes away and everything works.` is your answer.

Comment: Thats right I forgot this is a route and i need to add the view....let me try that. Damn i hate stupid mistakes...

Comment: You'll need to add `ng-view` in your index.html, then create the file `/app/partials/search.html`

Comment: @JonathandeM. Okay still getting the same error.... I will update my code. Routing it to the html file now with ng-view is still throwing the same error, even though the html from the view is loading.

Comment: `<div ng-controller="SearchCtrl"><ng-view></ng-view></div>` remove the ng-controller

Comment: @JonathandeM. sorry i did in my code....just forgot to update here. Am I setting up that controller okay with requirejs? Im still trying to figure out how to get the ng modules around inside requirejs.

Comment: Update the error message

Comment: You didnt declare your search-ctrl.js in requirejs, check in your console whether the file is loaded

Comment: @JonathandeM. Oh, but I declared components and I am requiring components/search/search-ctrl. Can I not do that? It is loading the file properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55293/discussion-between-metropolis-and-jonathan-de-m).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module need to work for angular and requirejs, your module was only linking through requirejs. Change to:

app.js

```
define("app", ["angular", "routes", "angular-resource", "angular-route", 
        "jQuery", "components/search/search-ctrl"], function (angular, routes) {

    var app = angular.module("app", ["ngResource", "ngRoute", "app.search"]);

    angular.element().ready(function() {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"]);
    });

    return app;
});
```

search-ctrl.js

```
'use strict';

define("search", ["angular", "angular-resource"], function(angular) {
    var search = angular.module('app.search', []);
    return search;
});

require(["search"], function(search) {
    search.controller("SearchCtlr", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
        $scope.person = {
            name: "Blah"
        };
    }]);
});
```

Comment: Sweet man thats a lot closer. I am getting an uncaught object now, which is present even if I take on the ng-view element now.

Comment: Wait! I got it! Thanks a ton man, that just taught me a good lesson.

Comment: Thanks man! Its coming along slowly since I am having to learn Angular, but I am getting it more and more.